# Why viewport is getting to slow despite blender runs on Intel 6 cores CPU?

Tags: 3d-view

Im running Blender 2.79 on Linux Debian with the new Intel Core i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz and a 16Gb of RAM. I made 40 metaball spheres for testing speed and memory. Unfortunately i saw that the speed of the viewport was dramatically slow in order to move objects around. Is this something that we expect or i must adjust some settings to achieve better speed ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What leads you believe it should preform better? Viewport performance is mostly dependent on GPU, and to a lesser extent CPU. There are however limitations and inefficiencies that place limits on this.

Comment: Im not sure how blender handles things when GPU is missing. I thought that with a strong CPU and lot of memory things would be faster in order to move around models with high complexity.I think you have right about GPU and how it helps in view-port performance.